# Is it possible to register QML type from object, not from class?

Tags: c++, qt, class, object, qml

When I create a class in C++, I can register it for QML and can create view for it. It's very convenient. But, if I need many objects of the same type, and need to show few views on screen, I got problems.
Is it possible to register QML type for object, not for class?
If I change some object, I need to see only its view changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export objects to QML engine using setContextProperty :

```
// C++ code
MyObject myObject;
QQmlEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myObject", &myObject);

// QML code
Text {
    text: myObject.name
}
```

Comment: I've already found this solution: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html It helps. Thanks.